# Reservoir of LSM vs. FF-NN or ELM

Tags: recurrent-neural-networks

The reservoir of the Liquid State Machine is an array of random numbers connected to each other with a probability depending on the distance between each other. Because of this connection with each other it apparently has "recurrence". The reservoir is followed by a readout stage where the actual weight training is done.

The hidden layer of a FF-NN can be an array of random weights, which is exactly what an Extreme Learning Machine is. ELM has a closed form solution of the second-stage weight (Beta) calculation i.e. only the Beta needs to be trained.

So in both cases you have a second-stage layer or readout layer where weights are trained.

My question is, if the reservoir random weights are very much like the ELM random weights and both don't need to be trained, how are they any different than each other? In other words, both have a set of untrained random weights, so in LSM where is the recurrence exactly happening if the weights are just random? Can't the LSM be reduced to a FF-NN?